# Shortest Method To Reference A Single Row/Column of a Named Range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I have a named range (`NamedRange1`) and I need to reference the first row and first column of that range within a formula. I came up with the following:

- First row:

  `INDIRECT("R" & ROW(UnpivotSource) & "C" & COLUMN(UnpivotSource) & ":R"& ROWS(UnpivotSource) +ROW(UnpivotSource) -1 & "C" & COLUMN(UnpivotSource),0)`
- First column:

  `INDIRECT("R" & ROW(UnpivotSource) & "C" & COLUMN(UnpivotSource) & ":R"& ROW(UnpivotSource) & "C" & COLUMNS(UnpivotSource) + COLUMN(UnpivotSource) -1,0)`

This seems cumbersome, especially since the Excel object model exposes `Rows` and `Columns` in VBA. Is there a more concise way of expressing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Row:

```
INDEX(UnpivotSource,1,0)
```

Column:

```
INDEX(UnpivotSource,0,1)
```

Note that this will only work for contiguous named-ranges, there's an index function for areas of a range, but it could get tricky if you wanted something other than the first row or column.

Comment: Beautiful, works great and way shorter. Thanks!

Comment: Under the hood of xl do you think if I use this technique, for say Max, it will be more efficient e.g. `Max("A:A")` compared to `Max(index(myNmdRang,0,1))` ?

Comment: @whytheq, My guess would be that for large columns `Max("A:A")` would be the most efficient. You could time and test, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198409/how-do-you-test-running-time-of-vba-code.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I added a more detailed question on S.O here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197157/is-specifying-a-column-from-a-named-range-more-efficient-than-calculating-over-a You might like to answer as the current answer is not good enough.